# Any way to customize Windows 10 Search (or replace with other)?

Tags: search-folder

I am surprised how unfriendly is Windows 10 search.

> [image]

- it doesn't have columns to be sortable (i.e. by size, name or etc..)
- it doesn't have to open that file location "in new window" (when you open location folder and try to go back to "results", Explorer makes the search again)
- it doesn't have any way to extend the column width (thus, I can't see the path fully!)
- when you open the folder (from search results) you cant find out its address easily (because it shows: [image] ) and we only have to right click> go Properties>  copying the folder path from there.

**Question:** Is there any way to replace it with 3rd party tool, like it was accessible easily as native Windows search? (from folder window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Windows *Search* has its limitations, use the *Details* view to see all the usual columns.

[image: Windows Search options]

To see *Details*, click on the icon at bottom or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>. If the same folder is searched again, the view defaults to *Details*. That said, there are two nuisances:

- There appears to be no *global* setting for *Search* view - only *per folder*.
- Though you can sort on any column (even ones you might add, such as *Frame width*), clicking on the header starts the search afresh - which can be time consuming.

You can open a *folder*, though not a file, found in *Search* by right-clicking and selecting *Open in a new window*.

There are useful third-party search tools, such as [Doc Fetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html), which even indexes .epub and other files that MS cannot, and [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) from Mythicsoft, which has numerous search options, including RegEx.

Comment: thanks, nice answer. however, my main problem was that i wanted file's folder to be opened in new window, (instead of folders)

Comment: Though I tried to create a *SendTo* shortcut to send a file's location to Explorer, I have not yet been able to get it to work. Perhaps someone can combine these two parts: 1) Create a shortcut in SendTo to CMD.exe.  2) In the CMD prompt, *%windir%\explorer.exe %cd%* opens Explorer to the location of the file submitted to SendTo. However, I've not been able to get Explorer to open directly. sigh.